# Couldn`t access form controls in array notation function

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetTransactionService } from '../../../service/getTransaction/get-transaction.service';
import { Router, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transactions',
  templateUrl: './transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transactions.component.css']
})
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _data: GetTransactionService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            ordSearch: ['', Validators.required],
            fromDate: ['', Validators.required],
            toDate: ['', Validators.required],
            systemId: ['', Validators.required],
            entityId: ['', Validators.required],
            pmntMethod: ['', Validators.required],
            merchantId: ['', Validators.required],
            ordStatus: ['', Validators.required],
            refNumber: ['', Validators.required]

        });
   }

  public responseJSON;

  getTransactionDtls () {
      let transactionResponse = this._data.getTransactionDtls().subscribe(
          success => {
              console.log(success);
              this.responseJSON = success;
             // this.populateOrder(success);
          }, error => {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );;
  }


  datePopulate = (event) => {
      let target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currenTarget;
      let label = target.innerText;
      let currentDate = new Date();
      let date = currentDate.getDate();
      let month = currentDate.getMonth();
      let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      let currentDateFormat = date + "-" + month + "-" + year;

      switch (label) {
          case "Today": {
              this.form.controls[fromDate].setValue(currentDateFormat);
          }
          case "Yesterday": {

          }
          case "This Week": {

          }
          case "Last Week": {

          }
          case "This Month": {

          }
          case "Last Month": {

          }
      }
  }

}
```

`this.form.controls[fromDate].setValue(currentDateFormat)`, I getting error in fromDate with "cannot find name", this is working with normal function like   `datePopulate = function (event) { and changed the value set as this.form.controls.fromDate.setValue(currentDateFormat);`

Kindly help me set value with array notation function

Comment: there is not let variable name `fromDate` in the component

Answer (score 0):

wrap it around `''`

```
 this.form.controls['fromDate'].setValue(currentDateFormat);
```